# Does Spatial Index make feature class faster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, performance, spatial-index

Does spatial index make dataset work faster?

Are there any disadvantages in having it?

All datasets in my sde don't have a spatial index. I thought I should add it to make things faster

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] that describes our focused Q&A format.  When you tested did you find that a spatial index made a dataset work faster?

Comment: Depending on your database you may already have a spatial index, PostGIS, from what I remember, adds a spatial index by default. It would be interesting though to test/record your transactions prior to indexing and then again after indexing to see if a spatial index improved performance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, spatial indexes makes the spatial query faster. Check this:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-spatial-indexes-in-the-geodatabase.htm

Comment: However, it depends on the query. The speed is better if the query contains a spatial part that is selective enough. For example, if you select with a bounding box that covers all the data then spatial index makes things slightly slower (check the index and select everything vs. just select everything).

Comment: Indexes will be of no use if the optimizer determines that the query requires a full table scan. The presence of indexes slows insert operations,  but usually the cost is offset by indexed query speed.